# Docker option2, transport is closing error

Tags: hyperledger

I was trying the simple chain code, with membersvc and validation peer running in  Docker for Mac. I got this error when running the chain code example 2:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:30303 ./chaincode_example02
16:58:41.242 [shim] DEBU : Peer address: localhost:30303
16:58:41.244 [shim] DEBU : os.Args returns: [./chaincode_example02]
16:58:41.244 [shim] DEBU : Registering.. sending REGISTER
2016/08/22 16:58:41 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken EOF.
16:58:41.245 [shim] ERRO : Received error from server: rpc error: code = 13 desc = "transport is closing", ending chaincode stream
Error starting Simple chaincode: rpc error: code = 13 desc = "transport is closing"
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved with the latest docker build with the latest docker-compose file.

Comment: Hi @E Ma i run into the same issue, the hyperledger i am using is 1.1.0-Preview.  i create the orderer, peers manually by following the official examples(http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html), but when i try to install the chaincode to peers , it not worked and throw me the error message .. do you have any idea about how to solve this issue ?